# Free Windows utility that I can use to check the quality of an SD card?

Tags: sd-card

Is there a free Windows utility that I can use to check the quality of an [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital)?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "quality". If you hope to get an answer I think you'll have to add more details about what you are hoping to learn to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The standard version of *[Flash Memory Toolkit](http://www.flashmemorytoolkit.com/info.html)* is free, although the write error and benchmarking tests are disabled. Bear in mind that even just making these tests ***reduces the life*** of your flash memory.